# How to operate the transaction of cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

In my project, I use the spring, but the cassandra cannot support transaction. How to operate the transaction of cassandra in service layer?

Comment: perform multiple queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log every transaction you carry out, store them in a log file of some sort and when you want to undo it create a query that does the opposite of what you just did.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think differently in noSQL.  Read Building on Quicksand http://www-db.cs.wisc.edu/cidr/cidr2009/Paper_133.pdf.  If using cassandra, you may want to check out PlayOrm as well and the nosql patterns page.